# Solve slow to provide answers for system of coupled equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of coupled equations that I am trying to solve using the Solve function. However, I've tried to solve it a few times using Mathematica 13.3 and so far I haven't been able to get anything.
It's simply too slow to provide any answers. I would like to know if it is possible to speed it up somehow or perhaps use another faster function that will solve the problem. The equations and what I've tried so far are shown below and they must be solved for r11, r33, r44, r12, r21, r13, r31, r14, r41, r23, r32, r24, r42, r34 and r43.

```
FullSimplify[Solve[{I \[CapitalOmega]12c/2 r12 - I \[CapitalOmega]12/2 r21 + \[CapitalGamma]21 (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) + \[CapitalGamma]41 r44 + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] (r24 + r42) == 0, (*r11*)
    
I \[CapitalOmega]34c/2 r34 - I \[CapitalOmega]34/2 r43 + \[CapitalGamma]23 (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) + \[CapitalGamma]43 r44 + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43] (r24 + r42) == 0, (*r33*)

    I \[CapitalOmega]34/2 r43 - I \[CapitalOmega]34c/2 r34 - (\[CapitalGamma]41 + \[CapitalGamma]43) r44 - 1/2 (r24 + r42) (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r44*)

    -I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]21) r12 + I \[CapitalOmega]12/2 r11 - I \[CapitalOmega]12/2 (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) - 1/2 r12 (\[CapitalGamma]21 + \[CapitalGamma]23) - 1/2 r14 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0, (*r12*)

    I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]21) r21 - I \[CapitalOmega]12/2 r11 + I \[CapitalOmega]12/2 (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) - 1/2 r21 (\[CapitalGamma]21 + \[CapitalGamma]23) - 1/2 r41 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r21*)

    I \[Omega]31 r13 + I/2 (r14 \[CapitalOmega]34c - r23 \[CapitalOmega]12) + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]23] (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]41*\[CapitalGamma]43] r44 + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]43] r24 + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]41] r42 == 0,(*r13*)

    -I \[Omega]31 r31 - I/2 (r41 \[CapitalOmega]34 - r32 \[CapitalOmega]12c) + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]23] (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]41*\[CapitalGamma]43] r44 + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]43] r42 + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]41] r24 == 0,(*r31*)

    -I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]41) r14 + I/2 (r13 \[CapitalOmega]34 - r24 \[CapitalOmega]12) - 1/2 r14 (\[CapitalGamma]41 + \[CapitalGamma]43) - 1/2 r12 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r14*)

    I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]41) r41 - I/2 (r31 \[CapitalOmega]34c - r42 \[CapitalOmega]12c) - 1/2 r41 (\[CapitalGamma]41 + \[CapitalGamma]43) - 1/2 r21 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r41*)

    I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]23) r23 + I/2 (r24 \[CapitalOmega]34c - r13 \[CapitalOmega]12c) - 1/2 r23 (\[CapitalGamma]21 + \[CapitalGamma]23) - 1/2 r43 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r23*)

    -I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]23) r32 - I/2 (r42 \[CapitalOmega]34 - r31 \[CapitalOmega]12) - 1/2 r32 (\[CapitalGamma]21 + \[CapitalGamma]23) - 1/2 r34 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r32*)

    I \[Omega]42 r24+I/2 (r23 \[CapitalOmega]34-r14 \[CapitalOmega]12c)-1/2 r24(\[CapitalGamma]21+\[CapitalGamma]23+\[CapitalGamma]41+\[CapitalGamma]43)-1/2 r44(Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41]+Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43])-1/2 (1-r11-r33-r44)(Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41]+Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43])==0,(*r24*)

    -I \[Omega]42 r24 - I/2 (r32 \[CapitalOmega]34c - r41 \[CapitalOmega]12) - 1/2 r42 (\[CapitalGamma]21 + \[CapitalGamma]23 + \[CapitalGamma]41 + \[CapitalGamma]43) - 1/2 r44 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) - 1/2 (1 - r11 - r33 - r44) (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r42*)

    -I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]43) r34 - I/2 (r44 - r33) \[CapitalOmega]34 - 1/2 r34 (\[CapitalGamma]41 + \[CapitalGamma]43) - 1/2 r32 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0,(*r34*)
   
 I (\[Omega] - \[Omega]43) r43 + I/2 (r44 - r33) \[CapitalOmega]34c - 1/2 r43 (\[CapitalGamma]41 + \[CapitalGamma]43) - 1/2 r23 (Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]21*\[CapitalGamma]41] + Sqrt[\[CapitalGamma]23*\[CapitalGamma]43]) == 0(*r43*)
    
} /. {\[CapitalOmega]12c -> \[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalOmega]34c -> \[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalOmega]12 -> \[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalOmega]34 -> \[CapitalOmega], \[CapitalGamma]21 -> \[CapitalGamma], \[CapitalGamma]23 -> \[CapitalGamma], \[CapitalGamma]41 -> \[CapitalGamma], \[CapitalGamma]43 -> \[CapitalGamma]}, {r11, r33,r44, r12, r21, r13, r31, r14, r41, r23, r32, r24, r42, r34, r43}], 
 Assumptions -> {\[CapitalOmega]12 > 0, \[CapitalOmega]12c > 0, \[CapitalOmega]34c > 0, \[CapitalOmega]34 > 0, \[CapitalGamma]21 > 0, \[CapitalGamma]23 > 0, \[CapitalGamma]41 > 0, \[CapitalGamma]43 > 0}]
```

Obs: I would like to get the most general solutions, but if it helps to speed up, all omegas can be taken as equal as well as gammas, that is, $\Omega_{12}=\Omega_{12c}=\Omega_{34}=\Omega_{34c}\equiv \Omega$  and  $\Gamma_{21}=\Gamma_{23}=\Gamma_{41}=\Gamma_{43}\equiv \Gamma$.

Comment: What happens if you avoid the FullSimplify? Does Solve still take a long time? Do you get an answer in the special case (all omegas equal etc)?

Comment: I tried the route you suggested by removing FullSimplify. Now I'm getting results for both the situation where all omegas and gammas are the same, as well as for the more general case. Previously, I had equations that were "less" coupled, and there FullSimplify worked fine. I thought it would happen again, but the expressions now are extremely complicated and long. That's why it was taking so much time. Thanks for the tip @MarcoB. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {I Ω12c/2 r12 - ... your equations ... + 
        Sqrt[Γ23*Γ43]) == 0(*r43*)};

eqns2 = Assuming[
   {Ω12 > 0, Ω12c > 0, Ω34c > 0, Ω34 > 0, Γ21 > 0, Γ23 > 0, 
    Γ41 > 0, Γ43 > 0}, eqns // Simplify];

eqns3 = Assuming[{Γ > 0, Ω > 0}, eqns2 /.
     {Ω12c -> Ω, Ω34c -> Ω, Ω12 -> Ω, Ω34 -> Ω, Γ21 -> Γ, 
      Γ23 -> Γ, Γ41 -> Γ, Γ43 -> Γ} // Simplify];

LeafCount /@ {eqns, eqns2, eqns3}

(* {904, 760, 447} *)

sol3 = Assuming[{Γ > 0, Ω > 0}, Solve[eqns3,
     {r11, r33, r44, r12, r21, r13, r31, r14, r41, r23, r32, 
      r24, r42, r34, r43}]][[1]];

LeafCount@sol3

(* 1852608 *)
```

Rather than trying to simplify all 15 expressions at once, simplify them one at a time. You will need to increase the `TimeConstraint` value in `Simplify` (do not use `FullSimplify`).

```
LeafCount /@ sol3

(* {78026, 116730, 116743, 131161, 131017, 125381, 125381, 127429, 
    127571, 126211, 126947, 136909, 129549, 126819, 126733} *)
```

Comment: I didn't expect that the results could have such long expressions. I ended up relying on another, simpler case of these equations that provided me with results more quickly. I assumed the same thing would happen here. Thank you for your help @Bob Hanlon